# How do I right align controls in a StatusStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip

I am trying to right align a control in a [`StatusStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.statusstrip.aspx). How can I do that?

I don't see a property to set on `ToolStripItem` controls that specifies their physical alignment on the parent `StatusStrip`.

[How do I get Messages drop down to be right aligned? http://i.friendfeed.com/ed90b205f64099687db30553daa79d075f280b90](http://i.friendfeed.com/ed90b205f64099687db30553daa79d075f280b90)

Comment: Make a label toolbar item with Spring property set to true.  Details: http://www.dotnetperls.com/statusstrip  (P.S. Yes, I know that it's an old question.)

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Found it via MSDN forums almost immediately after posting :)

You can use a [`ToolStripLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.aspx) to pseudo right align controls by setting the `Text` property to `string.Empty` and setting the `Spring` property to `true`.  This will cause it to fill all of the available space and push all the controls to the right of the [`ToolStripLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.aspx) over.

Comment: This will work **ONLY** if `StatusStrip.LayoutStyle == ToolStripLayoutStyle.Table` (which is the default one)

Comment: Nice.  A StatusStripLabel with Spring on either side appears to center the controls

Comment: I wish there was a "real" way of doing this, but this works so thanks. I wonder what the `Alignment` property does, because it didn't do anything in my application.

Comment: _I wonder what the Alignment property does_ I don't see any such property.

Comment: This will only allow one item after the label with "Spring", the others will not appear, use @VBobCat method instead.

Answer (score 27):

For me it took two simple steps:

1. Set `MyRightIntendedToolStripItem.Alignment` to `Right`
2. Set `MyStatusStrip.LayoutStyle` to `HorizontalStackWithOverflow`

Comment: this worked for me but after that I could not resize the control :(

Answer (score 5):

As an added note this is due to the fact that in the Win32 API a cell is either fixed width or fills the remaining space -1

```
int statwidths[] = {100, -1};

SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETPARTS, sizeof(statwidths)/sizeof(int), (LPARAM)statwidths);
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Hi there :)");
```

If memory serves me correctly you can have only one fill cell (-1) per statusbar.

You could also add a third middle cell and give this the fill property to get a more concistent looking StatusBar. Consistent because Messages has an inset to its left right where you'd expect it. A bit like the mspaint shot found on the [MSDN page for StatusBars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760728(VS.85).aspx#Size_and_Height)

I like the creative appreach though :D

Comment: That's valid for StatusBars, not for StatusStrips, which are fully managed code.

Answer (score 4):

You can display the `Button` at the end of the `StatusStrip` by using the logic below.

1. Add a `ToolstripLabel` to the `StatusStrip`
2. Set text as `string.Empty`
3. Set `Padding` for the `ToolstripLabel`

For example:

```
this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Padding = new Padding((int)(this.Size.Width - 75), 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: _add a third middle cell and give this the fill property_  I don't see any such property.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a Toolstrip label , set Spring property as true and for label align text in  BottomLeft

Answer (score 2):

I found that you can set the StatusStrip Layout to HorizontalStackWithOverflow.
Then, for each control on the StatusStrip that you want on the right side, set the control Alignment to Right.

I like this better since you don't need any extra or dummy controls to align.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a status strip label control’s Spring property to true, then that label takes up any space not used by other controls in the StatusStrip.

Comment: This answer is already given. When answering such an old question with a lot of answers, you need to check this before.

Answer (score -4):

Set the RightToLeft tool strip property to True.